# Ajax не отправляет POST запрос

Tags: ajax, laravel, cors

Пытаюсь отправить POST запрос к API http://esb.intime.ua:8080/services/intime_api_3.0?wsdl.

```
                var settings = {
                    "async": true,
                    "crossDomain": true,
                    "url": "http://esb.intime.ua:8080/services/intime_api_3.0?wsdl=",
                    "method": "POST",
                    "headers": {
                        "content-type": "text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
                        "soapaction": "\\\"urn:get_locality_all\\\"",
                        "cache-control": "no-cache"
                },
                    "data": "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:dat=\"http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice\">\r\n   <soapenv:Header/>\r\n   <soapenv:Body>\r\n      <dat:get_locality_all>\r\n         <dat:api_key>(тут мой ключ)</dat:api_key>\r\n      </dat:get_locality_all>\r\n   </soapenv:Body>\r\n</soapenv:Envelope>"
                }

                $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                  console.log(response);
                });
```

В результате получаю - Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://esb.intime.ua:8080/services/intime_api_3.0?wsdl=. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Также в Network видно, что изспользуется метод OPTIONS, а не POST. Если убрать из запроса headers, то отправляется методом POST, то тогда я не получаю корректный ответ.
Вот мой cors.php:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Laravel CORS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*')
    | to accept any value.
    |
    */

    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,

];
```

Вот Kernel.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'priceError' => \App\Http\Middleware\ReturnDangerIfPriceError::class
    ];
}
```

Подскажите как починить) 
П.С.: laravel 5.6